# PHP error when get_the_terms of an objet in woo

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello i just got thos messages in debug.log of my wordpress / woocommerce website :

`[21-Jul-2020 17:33:33 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /home/lattyteskl/www/latty-com/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/functions.php on line 87 [21-Jul-2020 17:33:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object in /home/lattyteskl/www/latty-com/wp-content/themes/betheme-child/functions.php on line 87`

here is the code i use :

```
global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term->term_id == $OUTILLAGE_ID )
        {
            $cats[] = '<a href="/catalogue-produits/outillage/">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        }
```

Do you know how to get those terms in a better way ?

thank you

edit :
i add this line in the debug.log :

```
[23-Jul-2020 08:20:46 UTC] PHP Notice:  post was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/betheme-child/woocommerce/single-product.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no check in place for when `$terms` is empty. Also I think you want to call `$product` instead of `$post` here. Which will give you the option to get the id via the WooCommerce `get_id()` function. So your code should look something like this:

```
global $product;
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term->term_id == $OUTILLAGE_ID ) {
            $cats[] = '<a href="/catalogue-produits/outillage/">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        }
    }
}
```